# Drupal installation error message

Tags: drupal-8

i just got started learning about drupal. during installation an error message is shown in my browser.

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getPath() on a non-object in C:\xampp_folder\xampp\htdocs\drupal8\core\includes\install.core.inc on line 783`

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here are few simple instructions to follow when installing drupal7.x or drupal8
when having difficulties during installation of drupal7.x and drupal8.
please i recommend that you try installing lower versions of drupal before installing either drupal7 or drupal8. Thank you.

Comment: Do not use older versions of Drupal. The latest core versions may cover minor or major security issues to remove vulnerabilities & keep your site safe.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Even though i am new to drupal! i used drupal6.x at some point in time @BaikHo